# Laravel 10 mails are blocked, Outlook/Thunderbird mails not

Tags: laravel, laravel-10, laravel-mail, symfony-mailer

I am having problems sending emails via Laravel 10. The error message from the email server is clearly understandable. My IP address from the provider, which is shared with other customers, was blocked. But I can send mails from the same PC with the same IP via Thunderbird and Outlook using this email address and I am not blocked.
What does Laravel mailer do differently than Thunderbird and Outlook?

LOG.error: Expected response code "250/251/252" but got code "554", with message "554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [***.***.***.***] blocked using zen.spamhaus.org; [https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/***.***.***.***"](https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/***.***.***.***%22). {
"userId": 1,
"exception": {}
}

```
'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),
'mailers' => [
     'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'url' => env('MAIL_URL'),
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'foo.bar'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587), /* also tried 465 */
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'), /* also tried ssl */
            'username' => env('mail@foo.bar'),
            'password' => env('*********'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN', parse_url(env('APP_URL'))['host']), /* APP_URL is https://somelocalproject:8080, also tried localhost */
        ]
],
'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'mail@foo.bar'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Test-Mailer'),
],
```

Comment: Your app may or may not have spam send email thus getting this error. Is this error on production or on development/testing server?

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth Local development server (XAMPP PHP 8.1 Windows)

Comment: Since this is in local development, have you tried changing your smtp server? Something like mailtrap.io.

Comment: btw if it works on mailtrap but not in your original smtp, then the problem might be the smtp server was associated with spamming.